# Objective C - Not releasing memory when popping UITableViewController scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple project using Xcode 4.3.2 targeting iOS 5.1, using storyboards and a NavigationController.  I have just migrated the project to use ARC and I'm now noticing that memory isn't being reclaimed when my UITableViewController scene is popped (back button pressed).  I'm sure this was working OK when I was managing memory myself.  I'm using the 'Allocations' feature of the Instruments tool and I can see the 'Live Bytes' continues to increase each time the scene is pushed then popped.  The interface for the UITableViewController is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@interface StockListView : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *tableListArray;         
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBarControl;
}

@property (nonatomic) ASIHTTPRequest *httpDSRequest;

@end
```

The UITableView uses a custom UITableViewCell class defined as follows :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StockListCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStockCode;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDescription;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblQtyInStock;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblQtyFree;

@end
```

Is there something in the properties I'm using that is keeping the view controller retainined in memory?  Do I need to add some code to allow the view controller to fully deallocate now that I'm using ARC?

I also used the 'Leaks' feature of Instruments but this didn't show up any leaks present.

Any help appreciated, apologies I'm still new to iOS development.

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the buttons weak referenced

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblStockCode;
```

And maybe have a look at this: [ARC Transition](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)